# Remote debugging the server Jboss eap 6.4 is failing from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, remote-debugging, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to connect to JBoss eap 6.4 remotely using Eclipse for remote debugging purpose.
I have modified the following lines in "**standalone.bat**"

```
rem JBoss Bootstrap Script for Windows
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------

rem Use --debug to activate debug mode with an optional argument to specify the port
rem Usage : standalone.bat --debug
rem         standalone.bat --debug 9797

rem By default debug mode is disable.
set DEBUG_MODE=true
set DEBUG_PORT=8787
```

I have also modified the following line(just uncommented) in "**standalone.conf.bat**" file:

```
rem # Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

I am getting the following error when I try to connect JBoss server remotely:

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect
```

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Doublecheck that the host used on connection properties is the one jboss binds to (e.g.  via jboss.bind.adress)
- Check if JBoss-VM is really listening on the port 8787 (e.g. netstat /a)
- Check that no firewall comes in between.